# Why am I receiving 401 Unauthorized errors with my Doorkeeper configuration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, doorkeeper

I have a Rails 6.1 app using devise 4.7.1, doorkeeper 5.5.1, and devise-doorkeeper 1.2.0.

I'm trying to run through a (PKCE) OAuth flow, but the final step -- a POST request to `/oauth/token` -- returns a 401 Unauthorized error with the JSON content `{"error": "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."}`.

I'm confused about this, since the `/oauth/token` endpoint should be accessible to unauthenticated users as far as I understand. What's also weird (but perhaps a red herring) is that if I attempt to run the same POST request with curl, but remove the User-Agent header, it succeeds.

My current suspect is this block of code in `initializers/doorkeeper.rb`:

```rb
  resource_owner_authenticator do
    current_user || warden.authenticate!(scope: :user)
  end
```

This comes from the [Doorkeeper docs](https://doorkeeper.gitbook.io/guides/ruby-on-rails/configuration). By stepping through the code, I can see that it's the call to `warden.authenticate!` that returns a 401 error. Doorkeeper's `TokensController#create` is never called.

Is there any important step I'm missing that allows unauthenticated access to this `TokensController#create` endpoint?

Comment: It shouldn't even be getting to your `resource_owner_authenticator` block since `POST /oauth/token` is available to everyone. I think for some reason the `:doorkeeper_authorize!` before_action is getting called, perhaps you have it configured erroneously in your TokensController or a superclass?

Comment: Thanks @AaronBrager, that's very helpful! By knowing that `resource_owner_authenticator` wasn't meant to be hit at all, I was able to work backwards to identify the problem. In short, it was caused by our Ahoy analytics library. Will write a fuller description soon :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was caused by our use of the [Ahoy analytics library](https://github.com/ankane/ahoy).

By default, this library tracks all page visits in your Rails app. It tries to get the current user using `current_user || current_resource_owner`. Because `current_user` was still nil when POSTing to `/oauth/token`, getting `current_resource_owner` ended up calling our Doorkeeper `resource_owner_authenticator`, which returned the 401 error. [The source code for this is here](https://github.com/ankane/ahoy/blob/68e511dde5cafe08b0a1aa59988d3b57576f02f4/lib/ahoy.rb#L72).

This also explains why things worked as expected when unsetting the `User-Agent` header: with no user agent (or the user agent of e.g. curl), Ahoy treats the request as coming from a bot, and doesn't attempt to track it ([source code here](https://github.com/ankane/ahoy/blob/68e511dde5cafe08b0a1aa59988d3b57576f02f4/lib/ahoy/base_store.rb#L59)).

Our solution to this is to tell Ahoy to stop tracking all page views automatically by setting `Ahoy.api_only = true` in its configuration.

Comment: Interesting, nice find!

Comment: For a less invasive fix, I think you could use `skip_before_action :track_ahoy_visit` in the TokensController instead of `Ahoy.api_only = true`